# Infinite difference length of integer subsets

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics, integer-sequences

Let $A$ be a set of integers. In our recent researches, we've faced to the  following property and definition:

We say $A$ has infinite difference length, if

**(a)** For every integer $n$ there exist a number $k=2^q$ (for some positive integer $q$) and $a_1,\cdots,a_k\in A$ such that 
$$
n=a_1+\cdots+a_{\frac{k}{2}}-(a_{\frac{k}{2}+1}+\cdots+a_k).
$$

Now, denote by $k(n)$ the least $k$ obtained from (a).

**(b)** The set of all $k(n)$, where $n$ runs over all integers, is unbounded above.

For example, if $\gcd\{a,b\}=1$ then $A=\{a,b\}$ has infinite difference length, but not $A=\mathbb{Z}^+$ (it does not have the second condition (b)).

Now, my questions are:

**(1)** Does the set of all Fibonacci numbers have infinite difference length?
(see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989375/representation-of-integers-by-fibonacci-numbers)

**(2)** What about the Euler numbers?

**(3)** Does anybody know some important well-known integer sequences with infinite difference lengths?

**(4)** Did anyone see something like the above property (definition) yet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In (a), do you assume $a_i\ne a_j$?

Comment: @Seva. Not necessarily.

Comment: Condition 1 is satisfied if and only if $\mathcal{A}$ contains two coprime integers. Condition 2 is satisfied if and only if $\mathcal{A}$ is not a basis of the integers. In particular all sets containing two coprime integers and having counting function $x^\epsilon$. In particular this holds for the FIbonacci numbers.

Comment: @Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta. Could you please prove your claim

Comment: $\mathcal A = \{6,10,15\}$ satisfies condition (a) but does not contain two coprime integers.

Comment: @Greg Martin: Oops, right. Since the condition is shift invariant, we may assume $0\in\mathcal{A}$. Then I claim that $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies condition 1 if and only if the greatest common divisor of all elements in $\mathcal{A}$ is 1. Every sufficiently large integer can be written as the sum of elements of $\mathcal{A}$, since we are allowed to take elements repeatedly. Using 0 as padding we can take $k$ as large as we want. In particular if $m, n$ are sufficiently large integers, we can arrange $a_1+\dots+a_{k/2}=n$, $a_{k/2+1}+\dots+a_k=m$. Thus every integer can be written as $n-m$.

Comment: If the greatest common divisor $d$ is not 1, then all linear combinations are divisible by $d$, thus condition 1 fails.

Comment: @Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta. Thanks, but $A$ can be infinite.

Comment: If $\mathcal{A}$ is infinite, then the greatest common divisor of all elements is the greatest common divisor of some finite subset of $\mathcal{A}$. And if some subset of $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies condition 1, then so does $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Note that the second condition is very important for the study, any idea?

Comment: I don't understand why $A=\{2,5\}$ satisfies (a). It seems that $a_1+\dots+a_{k/2}-(a_{k/2+1}+\dots+a_k)$ should always be divisible by 3...

Comment: @Ilya Bogdanov: The conditions in the question are. So you can shift one of the integers to 0, and then every integer can be represented if and only if the gcd is 1.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta Sure, tHat's true. Sorry, the first time I read your comment I misunderstood it.